# Multiple search field codeigniter database error unknown column 'array' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, search

I want to add multiple search fields in my script.

The controller:

```
public function rekap(){
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user');
    if(empty($user)){
        redirect(base_url());
    }
    $profile = $this->user_model->get_user($user['user_id']);
    if($profile['status_user']=='Inactive' || $profile['token']!=$user['token']){
        redirect(base_url('logout'));
    }
    $this->load->view('rekap'); 
}
```

The model:

```
public function rekap($season,$username,$game){
    $this->db->where('id_season',$season);
    $this->db->where('id_username',$username);
    $this->db->where('game',$game);
    $result = $this->db->get('log',10000,0);

    return $data;
}
```

The view:

```
<div style='padding-left:10px'>
        <div class='border-blur' style='padding:5px'>
            <div style='padding-bottom:5px'>
                <form class='uk-form' method='GET' action='<?php echo base_url('Report/rekap_detail'); ?>'>
                    <input name='season' type='text' placeholder='season' value='<?php echo $_GET['season']; ?>' />
                    <input name='id_username' type='text' placeholder='id_username' value='<?php echo $_GET['id_username']; ?>' />
                    <input name='game' type='text' placeholder='game' value='<?php echo $_GET['game']; ?>' />                       
                    <button class='uk-button uk-button-primary'><span class='fa fa-search'></span> Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

I got this erorr

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 427 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php
>
> Line Number: 427
>
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM (`log`) WHERE `id_seasons` = '0018' AND `id_username` =
>   Array AND `game` = Array LIMIT 10000
>
> Filename: \database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Comment: You need to give out some more codes. Here I cannot see the model function 'rekap' being called anywhere. Give the code where that method is being called and what arguments are being supplied to it.

Comment: Your given controller code doesn't seem to be relevant to the question at all.but looking at the error , the problem is that you have passed wrong values to the `$game` and `username` of `rekap` model function .Neither `$game` nor `username` can accept an array but it looks that you have supplied those with arrays. The error probably lives in the place where you call `rekap` model function. Post the code where you call `rekap` model function.